# Why was Kronecker dissatisfied with Cantor's submitted paper?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, set-theory, cantor, kronecker

It is said [here](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ehistory/HistTopics/Beginnings_of_set_theory.html) that

> In 1874 Cantor published an article in Crelle's Journal which marks the birth of set theory. A follow-up paper was submitted by Cantor to Crelle's Journal in 1878 but already set theory was becoming the centre of controversy. Kronecker, who was on the editorial staff of Crelle's Journal, was unhappy about the revolutionary new ideas contained in Cantor's paper.

However the authors of the entry don't elaborate on reasons why Kronecker was so unhappy, which prompted my curiosity.

Comment: Kronecker wasn't willing to accept a ....   *delta* .... to his own theory.  // rim shot

Comment: You can see the post [did-kronecker-say-that-set-theory-is-not-mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6159/did-kronecker-say-that-set-theory-is-not-mathematics) for links to Kronecker's attitude with set theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I can't access the book supplied in the link in mention, unfortunately. So still waiting for an answer, a concise one perhaps.

Comment: Another consideration for the answer may be the dispute among the editors of *Crelle's Journal*, leading up to the expulsion of Kronecker from the board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About Kronecker's views on "foundational" issues, you can see:

- Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen, [Constructivism in mathematics: An Introduction. Volume 1](https://books.google.it/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC) (1988), page 17.

There is no "explicit" philosophy of mathematics in Kronecker's works.

He may be regarded as a "constructivist", or perhaps as a precursor of the *finitist* approach.

In his essay "Uber den Zahlbegriff" (1887) he outlined the project of "arithmetizing" Algebra and Analysis; that is, to found these disciplines on the fundamental notion of number, avoiding thus geometrical intuition.

In his arithmetization project he considered a mathematical definition acceptable only if it could be checked in a finite number of steps, criticizing the "pure" existence proofs. He stated that an existence proof for a number could be considered correct only if it contained a method to find the number whose existence was proven.

Some of his remarks belong to mathematical folklore, like his widely reported statement that:

> "the Lord made the natural numbers (*ganze Zahlen*), everything else is the work of men";

the same idea is reiterated in the following statement:

> "I consider mathematics only as an abstraction of the arithmetical reality".

*Note*: for some references to Kronecker's opposition to Cantorian set theory, we can see José Ferreirós, [Labyrinth of Thought: A History of Set Theory and Its Role in Modern Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=vrQLbbxGNMsC), Birkhäuser (2007), *sub voce*.

In conclusion, it seems that Kronecker never published his critique of Cantor's theory, but we can conjecture from the sources above that he disliked Cantor's new theory of the "arithmetics of the *infinite*" as well as Cantor's wide use of "pure" existence proofs.

Comment: You may want to clarify that the "widely reported statement" may be apocriphal as we have no document by Kronecker containing such a statement.  Rather, it was reported by Weber after Kronecker was safely underground. Kronecker scholars have raised doubts about the accuracy of Weber's report.

Comment: @MikhailKatz based on [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3770/did-kronecker-attribute-immutable-origin-to-the-integers) it is probably **not** apocryphal.

Comment: @Spencer, the page you linked provides the following quote from Kronecker: "The principal difference between geometry and mechanics on one hand, and the other mathematical disciplines we comprehend under the name of \arithmetic, consists according to Gauss in this: the object of the latter, number, is a pure product of our mind, while space as well as time has reality also outside of our mind which we cannot fully prescribe a priori. (Kronecker, Uber den Zahlbegriff, 1887, p. 339)"  This quote is not apocryphal, and goes in the opposite direction of Weber's phrase.

Comment: @MikhailKatz So, assuming Weber is correct in claiming Kronecker made the famous quote, how do you reconcile the two?

Comment: @Spencer, we have on the one hand a direct quotation from Kronecker expressing anti-Platonist views, and on the other a report after Kronecker's death by Weber, phrased in reportedly "condescending" terminology (see the comment by Felscher at the post you linked).  The choice is yours.

Comment: Mauro, you claim that Kronecker's statement "I consider mathematics only as an abstraction of the arithmetical reality" (where is this from by the way?)  expressed what you claim to be "the same idea" as the comment reported by Weber.  Could you elaborate on why you think they are the same?  The latter could be interpreted as a Platonist statement, but the former is not necessarily so.